# How to use Mapster to do type level mapping, with special mapping logic?

Tags: mapster

```
public static void Initialize()
        {
            TypeAdapterConfig<string?, DateTime?>.NewConfig()
                .MapWith(s => Convert(s));
        }

private static DateTime? Convert(string? s) => DateTime.TryParseExact(
            s, "dd/MM/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date) ? date : null;
```

Here's my workaround. If I didn't use the separate private method, the overloads of MapWith won't allow the `?` operator as the expression argument. Is there any other built-in way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Did you find an answer? :)

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.